# Did I do anything wrong with this answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-question

I have a question about my Arqade post: [How to cope with choking when playing games?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/106207/how-to-cope-with-choking-when-playing-games/351986#351986)

Is there anything I did actually wrong with this answer? I'm just new here and worried about the -3 that quickly appeared in response to this one, with no explanation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe the main reason for the downvotes would be the fact that you answered a 6 year old question that already had an accepted answer.

Also, possibly, the fact that you're advocating the use of alcohol and cannabis as a way to help gaming, which could jive badly with some users.

[Obligatory 'Tim lost his keys' post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/261140)

Comment: I did realize, but too late, that the last response was six years old. Still, for anyone looking for this information now, I did provide psychological information above and beyond what was given to date NOT related to alcohol or cannabis (though I mentioned the latter two too for my own use.) At any rate I thought that information might be useful, and in fact cover those people who DO like to use those substances in their video gaming. I'm not so sure about there being an "accepted" answer there, and if people keep being mean to me with poor explanation then I will delete my account.

Comment: The post was in fact SIX years old, not nine. It's still an old post, but it would be nice to get the number of years old that any given post is, too. I rest my case otherwise, whatever anyone might think of it, though if people continue to be mean and shady towards newbies like me, I will delete my account and cut my emotional losses aka how much I'm gaslit by the Stack Exchange community. At any rate only being allowed to edit a post for five minutes afterwards really hurts...

Comment: @Guitar - Firstly thank you for reaching out for feedback! It doesn't happen often enough. Downvoters aren't being mean - they're expressing disagreement with your answer. It's not a personal thing, that's [how we organise content](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) around here. As for editing comments - yeah they have a 5 minute window as comments are pretty minor. Note that questions and answers can be edited at any point. As a workaround for comments - if you desperately need to change something - you should consider rewriting the comment and deleting the old one.

Comment: I'm not sure why I said 9 when it was clearly 6 years. I must've been tired at the time :P

Comment: The lost keys idea means that people should not focus too hard on a single downvote, which is not necessarily indicative of a bad post. When you get 5 downvotes on a post, you should probably look at your post objectively, because it's pretty likely there's something wrong with it. Dismissing that kind of score due to "the phase of the moon" or anything else is just refusing to acknowledge what other users think of the post.

Comment: I really, really like the support and honest advice I have been given here! I was incredibly pleased to leave Stack Exchange for roughly two weeks with 40 rep, and come back with 105!! Probably a few of those upvotes were "sympathy" ones but still. I have also been made clear that people can do what they want with their votes here, so I shouldn't fret about that, especially with some sort of limit on it, particularly with the higher rep requirement to downvote (which I'm not quite at yet, though once again, 100 rep is a major milestone for me!!)